# camelCase format table name in Laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

I want to create a table by migration with name "blogOST".

But Laravel create a table is "blogpost".
In Laravel, how to use migration to create table name with camelCase format.

This is my migration code

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateOrderDetailTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blogPost', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title', 100);
            $table->dateTime('createdAt');
            $table->dateTime('updatedAt');
            $table->dateTime('deletedAt')->nullable();
            $table->charset = 'utf8';
            $table->collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('orderdetail');
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the migration please (probably is enough to specify the camel Case in the Schema name passed as string)

Comment: Thank you. I had post migration code.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it`s a common way to use`snake case`for table names and column names, Not only`Laravel` but also other languages uses same practice.

In `Laravel Eloquent Model` automatically maps to `lower case plural` table name. You can explicitly mention different table name if you want using `protected $table = 'my_table_name';`

So it`s Laravel`s default behavior.